# Box Office Java Problem, Problem with the misaglinment for the gross column

Tags: java

Create a BoxOffice application that outputs the top 10 movies at the box office. Be sure to use the
printf() method to align the columns and specify field widths. You should be able to find a common
number for all your Ranks, Titles and Gross fields. This means the field width should all be the same,
but the text is what changes.

This is what the question asked. I had put this code into java, but the alignment was something that is bugging me and dont know how to fix.

```
System.out.println("\t\t\tTOP WEEKND BOX OFFICE\n");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","Rank","Title","Gross");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","1","No Good Dead","24.2 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","2","Dolphin Tale 2","15.9 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","3","Guardians Of The Galaxy","8.1 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","4","Teenage Mutant Ninja Turtles","4.9 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","5","Let's Be Cops","4.3 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","6","The Drops","4.1 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","7","If I Stay","3.9 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","8","The November Man","2.8 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","9","The Giver","2.6 M");
    System.out.printf("%-10s%-20s%38s\n","10","The Hundred-Foot Journey","2.4 M");
```

Comment: So, ask yourself this question; What happens when the contents of a column is longer then the allocated width of the column?  When you can answer that, you will find an answer to your question

Comment: Ohhhh I think I found the problem, it was due to not counting the charecters for the 4th line. Ty for the help friend!